# How to declare a libc function whose signature is different from the original definition

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, clang

To use external functions in my self-making compiler, I want to define them in c.
This is the code of `runtime.c`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

...

#undef getchar

struct string *getchar()
{int i=getc(stdin);
 if (i==EOF) return &empty;
 else return consts+i;
}
```

However, When I run the following command, it throws the following error.

```
$ clang -O3 -S -target mips -mcpu=mips32 -std=c89 runtime.c.
runtime.c:105:16: error: conflicting types for 'getchar'
struct string *getchar()
               ^
/usr/include/bits/stdio.h:47:1: note: previous definition is here
getchar (void)
^
1 error generated.
```

I see what is happenning, but I have no idea to disable the original definition of `getchar`'s signature. I have tried running command with `-fno-builtin` and `-fno-builtin-getchar`, but the results were unchanged.
This is a sample code of
[Andrew Appel's "Modern Compiler Implementation in ML"](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Eappel/modern/ml/chap12/runtime.c),
so it can be compiled correctly in a specific environment.
Please teach me how to solve this problem.

Comment: The code in your link is - at best - ancient and outdated.  *it can be compiled correctly in a specific environment*  I don't think that code conforms to any C standard.  It was probably wrong even when it was published. In other words, it probably never compiled cleanly.  [It's not even C89 compliant](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#4.1.2): "All external identifiers declared in any of the headers are reserved, whether or not the associated header is included."

Comment: What do you mean by “self-making compiler”? Is this a compiler you are making or something else? If you are making a compiler, why does it need a routine named `getchar` that is different from the standard C library routine? If it is your own compiler, you can change the names of the routines in it, so you can use `MyGetChar` instead of `getchar`.

Comment: Re “I have no idea to disable the original definition of getchar's signature”: Do not include the surrounding environment’s `<stdio.h>`. If you are making your own compiler, making your own headers that declare what you need.

Comment: @EricPostpischil As you said, I removed `stdio.h` and made my own header that includes what are needed, for example `extern int getc (FILE *__stream);`. Then I could declare `getchar` with no errors. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

`#undef getchar` does nothing as `getchar` is not a macro definition only function.

> but I have no idea to disable the original definition of getchar's
> signature.

Do not include `stdio.h`, but even this will not help too much as you will have duplicate definitions of the function and the program will most likely not link. `ld` will probably link if the object file containing your definition will be placed before the standard library.

You need to link without the standard library or (but it is not portable) discard `getchar` from the library in the linker script.

Comment: Re “`#undef getchar` does nothing as `getchar` is not a macro definition only function.”: The C standard permits the standard library header files to define a macro for a library function as well as declaring it as a function, and OP be using `#undef` to remove this macro definition to avoid an error they encountered prior to the one they are asking about in this question. The C standard says such an `#undef` may be used for this purpose.

Comment: Re “… you will have duplicate definitions of the function and the program will not link”: Linking with libraries typically does not link in a module from the library if the symbols it defines are already defined by modules previously linked in or are not used by modules previously linked in. So the presence if a `getchar` definition in the program would not cause a multiple definition error unless the library module defining it also defined some other symbol the program used but did not define.

Comment: @EricPostpischil in the OPs question scope it does nothing. It does not "undefine" the function prototype.

Comment: @EricPostpischil as I wrote - ld will probably link. Other linkers may not - it is in my answer.

Comment: Yes, it will do something, as I explained. In a program with `#include <stdio.h>` followed by any declaration of `getchar`, even the C standard one of `int *getchar(void);`, the compiler may report a syntax error because the `getchar` in the declaration is replaced by the replacement list of the macro defined by `<stdio.h>`. OP may have encountered that problem first and solved it by inserting `#undef getchar`.

Comment: Re “Other linkers may not - it is in my answer”: My comment quotes your answer as it was at the time. You edited it subsequently. Nonetheless, your answer now states “the program will most likely not link”, but the converse is true, the common behavior of linkers is not to include library modules that are not needed. It is not solely an `ld` behavior. The program most likely will link.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have modified it long before your comment

Comment: @EricPostpischil `Yes, it will do something, as I explained.` - judging by the errors shown it did nothing.

Comment: Re “seeing the errors it did nothing”: Do you mean you tested it in a C implementation you are using and concluded from that that it does nothing in OP’s C implementation?

Comment: @EricPostpischil -  *"Do you mean you tested it in a C implementation you are using and concluded from that that it does nothing in OP’s C implementation?"* ???? - error messages are in the OPs question. BTW this comment is rather rude - do you suggest that I am intellectually impaired?

Comment: Re “error messages are in the OPs question”: Those are the error messages OP gets **now**, not necessarily the errors OP was getting at the time they decided to add the `#undef getchar`. As I initially wrote, OP may have added `#undef getchar` “to avoid an error they encountered **prior** to the one they are asking about in this question.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil maybe the code he posted is not the one he is using. Or maybe he took a random clang error message he saw on the net?